# How to search the right word not other similar words in ORACLE SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to pick any customer who had entries that said that the staff created duplicate entries by commenting 'error' in the database.

But somehow, it picked up other words related to the error as per shown on this link
https://wordfind.com/contains/error/

PS: yes my work database is not about product or purchases or sales but a similar scenario 'error' or other word tho :)

> select
>
> (case when lower (comment_text) like '%error%' then 'Y' END)
> error_deets ,
>
> b.*
>
> from product b

also how to pick that word in the new column so I can double check those words to widen the search

I am using ORACLE SQL

Thank you

Comment: What exactly did you want to capture from the comment column? Could you share a sample data of that column? If you only want to filter the data with comments containing the word "error", you can use this condition: `REGEXP_LIKE(comment_text, '(^|\s)error(\s|$)')`

Comment: hi @MatthewFarant, it can be varied comments on each customer on each row, so the word that relates to the error, such as word 1 = data entry error, word 2 = xxx xxx xxx xxx terrorism group xxx xxx xxx, word 3 = xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx terrorist act xx xxx xx, word 4 = xxx xxx terroist act xxx xxx (this word is not deliberate mistake it is part of their typo word). Hence I need a new column to pick up the rest word that has word error among words sentences in 'xxx xxx xxx'. They input lower and upper words in the comments.

Comment: For 'error' input not related to 'terrorism' = some words that can be; entered in error, input error, admin in error etc ... has a very long list!!

Answer (score 1):

To pick up the word "error", not embedded into another word like "terrorism", you need regular expressions (regexp). In Perl you could use a very convenient construct "\b" meaning "word boundary", so the regexp would be "\berror\b". Unfortunately Oracle does not have this construct, but we can simulate it, by requiring "non-word" characters before and after "error" :

```
CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(comment_text, '\Werror\W', 'i') THEN 'Y' END
```

The third argument  'i' means "case-insensitive", so there is no need to lower() the data.

This assumes that the word "error" is somewhere in the middle of the string. If you also want to capture situations where "error" is at the beginning, you need the regexp `'(^|\W)error\W'` , meaning "either the start of the string, or a non-word character, followed by "error", followed by a non-word character".

Oracle function REGEXP_SUBSTR() could be used to extract some characters after the word "error" and report them in a column of the query.

Comment: thank you @dami  \b is not on this link , however I tried your method and it didn't work from my end and I will keep trying myself, https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/regexp_substr.php

Comment: what exactly didn't work ?